# Trying to use $scope.$apply(), but it throws an error "$scope.$apply is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, apply, angularjs-service

Trying to call the `$scope.$apply`, but throws an error saying:

> $scope.$apply is not a function

Following is the code :

```
function loadUnitChanged(event, data) {
        console.log('Event Info: ', event);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.cargoregisters = createArrayFromLoadUnit(data);
                });
            }, 2000);           
    }
```

=========================================================

```
 angular.module('portwin.cargo').controller('CargoController', function     ($rootScope, $location, $timeout, $mdDialog, cargoGateway) {
    var $scope = this;

    // Event handlers
    $rootScope.$on('cargodetails:loaded', cargoDetailBaseDataLoaded);
   $rootScope.$on('cargoRegistration:loaded',      cargoRegistrationBaseDataLoaded);
    $rootScope.$on('loadUnit:changed', loadUnitChanged);
    $rootScope.$on('loadUnit:Saved', updateLoadUnitAfterSave);
```

Comment: please show all code context. We don't know where you call this or where you declare this function or if `$scope` is injected

Comment: Is `$scope` injected properly?

Comment: If that function is declared in global namespace would be a problem

Comment: $scope.cargoregisters = createArrayFromLoadUnit(data); this works fine without the $apply

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Since you have access to $scope, based on your comments, I would just do this...

```
function loadUnitChanged(event, data) {
  console.log('Event Info: ', event);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.cargoregisters = createArrayFromLoadUnit(data);
    ...any other processing you want to do in this function...      
  }, 2000);           
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but my $scope works fine without $apply, so this means $scope is injected properly. Also, it's not just one field that gets bound in "$scope.cargoregisters = createArrayFromLoadUnit(data);" statement. There are a lots of fields that are getting bound here

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a private method instead of a scoped function? ie: $scope.loadUnitChanged() vs function loadUnitChanged
This can cause all kinds of buggy behavior when trying to interact with the controller scope without properly injecting it.

Comment: If you look at the controller code above, the "loadUnitChanged" function is getting is fired as a result of an event in another controller which broadcasts this event, and that's why used private function i.e. $rootScope.$on('loadUnit:changed', loadUnitChanged);

Comment: Since you say you have access to $scope, I don't understand what it is you need. I have tried to address this but your question was about $scope.$apply() throwing an error...

Comment: I mean, this code below works fine, I was trying to implement the $apply function, can you tell me how to do this:                                                                                               //setTimeout(function () {
                    //$scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.cargoregisters = createArrayFromLoadUnit(data);
                    //});
                //}, 2000);

Comment: Finally got it working by using $rootscope instead of $scope